# Does network manager really support tls-crypt-v2?

Tags: network-manager, openvpn

I've set up an [OpenVPN server](https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/services/vpn/openvpn/server) on my OpenWRT router. It offers **tls-crypt-v2** so I've used that.
To make sure that my Ubuntu 20.04LTS cooperates with it, I've updated whatever seemed handy according the internet:

```
mkdir -p /etc/apt/keyrings
curl -fsSL https://swupdate.openvpn.net/repos/repo-public.gpg | gpg --dearmor > /etc/apt/keyrings/openvpn-repo-public.gpg
echo "deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/openvpn-repo-public.gpg] https://build.openvpn.net/debian/openvpn/release/2.6 focal main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/openvpn-aptrepo.list
apt-get update
apt-get install openvpn
apt-get install openvpn-dco-dkms
```

So now I have OpenVPN 2.6.6, it must cooperate with the server. Which it does,

```
sudo openvpn --config client.ovpn
```

connects like a charm! It is time to import the .ovpn into network manager (NM).

And this is the point where I've stuck.

I've updated NM to play sure:

```
sudo apt install network-manager-openvpn network-manager-openvpn-gnome
```

Now I have nmcli version of 1.22.10, which according to [github](https://github.com/NetworkManager/NetworkManager-openvpn/commit/717a1d41be0b039778b4eb85bca57f9356bb87aa) looks fresh enough to tackle with tls-crypt-v2. Both importing via GUI and nmcli has failed. The latter says (despite its version number) that

```
Error: failed to import 'client.ovpn': configuration error: unsupported blob/xml element (line 9).
```

where line 9 is the tls-crypt-v2 tag. For long years NM isn't really the sharpest tool in the shed when it's about importing anyway. No problem, I've sliced the .ovpn into ca.crt, client.crt and client.key . After setting the connection up manually it still doesn't work. The only useful clues I've found in syslog:

```
Oct  3 13:08:10 gep2 nm-openvpn[29902]: TLS Error: TLS key negotiation failed to occur within 60 seconds (check your network connectivity)
Oct  3 13:08:10 gep2 nm-openvpn[29902]: TLS Error: TLS handshake failed
```

and in the router logs look like:

```
Tue Oct  3 13:10:24 2023 daemon.err openvpn(server)[2339]: TLS Error: could not determine wrapping from [AF_INET]100.112.152.143:48721
```

The weak point may be slicing and manual import, however they look straightforward.

Any idea how to step further?
Did anybody managed to make NM cooperate with anything tls-crypt-v2 related?

Comment: According to [the package index](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=network-manager-openvpn-gnome), `network-manager-openvpn` is at 1.8.12 in 20.04, but the commit you have linked to is only in 1.8.14 and newer. The nmcli version is unrelated as the openvpn module is developed and versioned separately.